# rhub PREPERROR on Linux due to ImageMagick++

Tags: r, imagemagick

I want to check a package with `rhub::check_for_cran()`. One of the package dependencies reguires `ggimage` which in turn requires `magick`. As stated in the [magick package documentation](https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/articles/intro.html), "On Linux you need to install the ImageMagick++ library". My question is, can I somehow do that so that the error disappear?

Check results:

- OK on Windows Server 2022, R-devel, 64 bit
- PREPERROR on Fedora Linux, R-devel, clang, gfortran
- PREPERROR on Ubuntu Linux 20.04.1 LTS, R-release, GCC

The relevant part of the result's log is posted below:

```
#> * installing *source* package ‘magick’ ...

5254#> ** package ‘magick’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

5255#> ** using staged installation

5256#> Package Magick++ was not found in the pkg-config search path.

5257#> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Magick++.pc'

5258#> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

5259#> Package 'Magick++', required by 'virtual:world', not found

5260#> Using PKG_CFLAGS=

5261#> Using PKG_LIBS=-lMagick++-6.Q16

5262#> --------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------

5263#> Configuration failed to find the Magick++ library. Try installing:

5264#> - deb: libmagick++-dev (Debian, Ubuntu)

5265#> - rpm: ImageMagick-c++-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)

5266#> - csw: imagemagick_dev (Solaris)

5267#> - brew imagemagick@6 (MacOS)

5268#> For Ubuntu versions Trusty (14.04) and Xenial (16.04) use our PPA:

5269#> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/imagemagick

5270#> sudo apt-get update

5271#> sudo apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev

5272#> If Magick++ is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your

5273#> PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a Magick++.pc file. If pkg-config

5274#> is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:

5275#> R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

5276#> -------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------

5277#> :1:10: fatal error: 'Magick++.h' file not found

5278#> #include

5279#> ^~~~~~~~~~~~

5280#> 1 error generated.
```

I could not find any relevant threads in stackoverflow, the github issue pages of the two packages (`rhub` and `magick`). Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Ioannis! Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Hello Santiago! I edited the question to include the three operating systems the check was executed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it looks like you are missing packages in your Linux ditributions. In order to check if you got installed the `imagemagick` package, open a terminal and type:

```
santiago@santiago-desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep imagemagick
ii  imagemagick                                   8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2                        amd64        image manipulation programs -- binaries
ii  imagemagick-6-common                          8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2                        all          image manipulation programs -- infrastructure
ii  imagemagick-6.q16                             8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2                        amd64        image manipulation programs -- quantum depth Q16
```

If nothing appears, that means you don't have the package installed. If so, in the Ubuntu distribution, you have to open again the terminal and type (I've allready got it installed):

```
santiago@santiago-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
imagemagick ya está en su versión más reciente (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3build2).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 4 no actualizados.
```

Then, I was able to install and load the `magick` package from R:

```
> library(magick)
Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.11.60
Enabled features: fontconfig, freetype, fftw, heic, lcms, pango, webp, x11
Disabled features: cairo, ghostscript, raw, rsvg
Using 8 threads
```

Hope it help.

EDIT:

Im running Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

EDIT 2:

This is far more complicated than I initially thought. I've realized that you are running remote versions of OS (Linux, Windows), with the `rhub` package, that is used for some type of testing wich I'm not familiarize. I also tried to reproduce the error, but it seems that only the package maintainers can do it:

```
> check_for_cran(path = "/home/santiago/Descargas/magick_2.7.3.tar.gz", platforms = "ubuntu-gcc-release:")

  ‘jeroen@berkeley.edu’ is not validated, or does not match the package maintainer's email.
  To validate it now, please enter the email address below. Note that R-hub will send a token to
  this address. If the address does not belong to you, quit now by pressing ENTER .

  Email address: santicapo666@hotmail.com

Error: Emails don't match, aborting
```

Im really close to deleting this answer alltogheter. All I can think is that you must get in touch with the admins of the remote versions of Linux (the maintainers of `rhub`?) and ask them to install the required packages.

EDIT 3:

One last possibility is using the Debian distros (debian-gcc-release:). Looks like Debian 10 (aka "Buster"), has the `imagemagick` package installed by default. See https://packages.debian.org/buster/allpackages.

On contrast, you cannot find it in the mainfest list for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233344/which-pre-installed-apps-ship-with-the-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-installation

Comment: Hello Santiago! Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes the checks are remote, meaning that I do not have any control over the OS installed packages. Unfortunately, the `rhub` maintainers do not seem to respond in github's open issues in general. Therefore, I will try the "EDIT 3" part of your answer. Thank you very much for you work and time!